# Memory efficient batch-pairwise KL divergence in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor, information-theory

Given a Batch tensor `S` of dimensions `BxD` where each row is a probability distribution over `D` dimensions, I want to calculate the batch-pairwise KL divergence matrix `KL` (of dimensions `BxB`) such that `KL[i,j] = KL-DIVERGENCE(S[i],S[j])`.

This works:

```
softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(dim = 1)
B,D = 100, 1000
S = softmax(torch.rand(B,D))
KL = torch.mean(S[:,None,:] * (S[:,None,:]/S).log(),dim = 2)
```

but is very memory inefficient. Is there a way to calculate this matrix more efficiently?

Thanks.